# Loading an Android project from git into Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I want to import a project from https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/DeskClock into Eclipse. What steps do I have to go through in addition to the downloading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you've checked out the source code, you should be able to say File -> New -> Other -> Android -> Android Project

[image]

On the New Android Project screen, choose "Create Project from existing source"
[image]

Choose the location 
[image]

Go to town.  This is assuming you have the Android plugin for Eclipse.

Comment: I'm not sure why, but a friend wasn't able to load my Android project into Eclipse if his directory structure was the same as mine.  If he put the project in another folder, he could successfully open the project.  Could this be because I've added an unnecessary file to source control?  If so, any ideas what it may be?